# How to create a "122112211221" series in php

Tags: php, loops, math, series

I need to use a `$counter` in my loop that returns a series like this :

1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1

Sadly I'm not so good with math, whatever i tried hit a dead-end. 
this is the last thing i tried.

```
$counter = 0;

while( statement ) {
    ++$counter;

    // Making sure the second element is loaded
    if( $counter > 2 )
        $twoloaded = true;

    if( $counter >= 2 )
        --$counter;

    echo '<article class="post post-style-' . $counter . '"> ....... </article>';
}
```

In the end i need to output an HTML like this :

```
<article class="post post-style-1">
    ...
</article>

<article class="post post-style-2">
    ...
</article>

<article class="post post-style-2">
    ...
</article>

<article class="post post-style-1">
    ...
</article>

<article class="post post-style-1">
    ...
</article>

<article class="post post-style-2">
    ...
</article>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A generic approach:

```
$pattern = [ 1, 2, 2, 1 ];   // or array( 1, 2, 2, 1 ); for PHP < 5.4
$idx = 0;

while ( expression ) {
    $number = $pattern[ $idx ++ % count( $pattern ) ];
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure `$pattern = [ 1, 2, 2, 1 ];` is valid php - maybe `$pattern = array(1,2,2,1);` ?

Comment: @Omnimusha That's PHP 5.4+; they're at 7 or so ;-)

Comment: Gotcha.. might as well add the alternate syntax for those using lower versions on xxamp like me. The code executed beautifully otherwise +1(2211221)

Comment: Allright, will do - Btw I'm running Debian stable and it ships with 5.6.

Comment: Much chagin - still running PHP 5.3.2 :(

Answer (score 1):

How about having a $repeated variable. You can use it to check if 1 or 2 being repeated before switching.

```
<?php

$counter = 1;
$repeated = 1;

while(true) {

    print '<article class="post post-style-' . $counter . '"> ....... </article>' . "\n";

    if($repeated == 2) {

        if($counter < 2) {

            $counter++;
        }
        else if ($counter == 2) {

            $counter--;
        }

        $repeated = 1;  
    }
    else {

        $repeated++;    
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: I appreciate your time but the code lacks at the beginning , it returns a 11221 series , it must be 12211221